# Texture not showing in viewport

Tags: modeling

The texture are not showing in 3ds viewport
how can i solve?

thanks guyz

[image]

Update:
Details of Material/Texture
[image]

thanks

Update:Attached file
[Suzanne.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zrCbXCCOGiCG8EPXC5GMB2hhjea_la_P/view?usp=sharing)

Last Update:
It works when i put an light and the style view on Material =D
[image]

thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome Tiago!

Try changing this to Material (not texture):
[image]

After that, add a light to your scene, should work :)

Comment: hi friend
I havd change for Texture, and still not showing =(

Comment: One more thing that comes in mind - enter edit mode (Tab), select all (A), press U -> Smart UV Project -> OK.
Does that help?

Comment: Still not showing... the monkey stay white

Comment: Update your question and add screenshot of the material tab while having monkey selected.
PS. Monkey's name is Suzanne :)

Comment: Cant see anything wrong, but I am not really experienced with blender render - try adding entire blend file for us to take a look at.

Comment: I see now, you are missing a light in your scene - I have edited my answer, try if it helps (it did work for me, just not on texture, but material view mode instead).